# taxonomy.php template won't display content from current taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to get a very simple Wordpress taxonomy.php page to display the relevant posts from that taxonomy. For some reason no content is being displayed.

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="unit col-2-12">
            <figure class="thumbnail">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { 
                      the_post_thumbnail();
                } ?>
                <figcaption>
                    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                    <h5><?php the_excerpt(); ?></h5>
                    <h6><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></h6>
                </figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Am I approaching the creation of an archive template incorrectly here? Surely it should be relatively straight forward to create this page?

The file taxonomy.php is being targeted, as I have checked that this  is the template being pulled in. A user is able to navigate to a 'page' named Index, where they will see a list of 6 custom taxonomies, each displaying 10-15 individual categories (this may not be the correct term here) within them. A user can then click on the categories to enter the page using taxonomy.php. Here I want to display a list of all posts assigned to that category. I hope that helps to clarify.

Thanks

Comment: You might use full `<?php` opening tags in your example (so we can discard that as the cause of your proble).

Comment: @JonSurrell thank for the suggestion, have updated question.

Comment: At first look, this seems fine. It's very difficult to debug without knowing what your theme directory looks like, what taxonomy you're referencing, and probably more information. Anything else you can provide may help find a solution.

Comment: Thanks, have updated the question as best possible.